# weird issue in asp.net when launching web app

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using VB.Net and VS 2008 to develop my web app (that was initially created by someone else).

When I launch the app, pretty much ALL the pages get loaded (by that I mean the page_load event is triggered). This happens even for pages that I created. When this happens, the app throws some errors (if a particular value has not been loaded from the database) and thus results in javascript errors (yellow icon at the bottom of IE).

How can I figure out "what" is causing the pages to load, and how can I prevent the pages from being loaded without code-prompting.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "even pages that I created". What do you mean that all the pages get loaded? Are you talking about user controls?

Comment: I mean aspx pages are being loaded

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what that means? Are other pages being loaded besides the page you're on? Are you hitting breakpoints on other pages or something?

Comment: Have you tried closing the dev server instances (system tray) and rebuilding the solution? If not, do that and try to run again.

Comment: You mean that - let's assume you have 10 aspx-pages in your Web-Application - all 10 are getting loaded at the same time as soon as you are loading your "default.aspx"? This sounds very strange.

Comment: When I launch the app, and I have a breakpoint on a page that should not be called at startup, that breakpoint gets triggered. Lets say I am developing "Stackoverflow.com" and I put a breakpoint on "James Johnson" profile page, I hit F5 to run the app... the breakpoint on James' profile page is triggered.

Comment: @DotNetRookie: Have you configured your IIS correctly(f.e. set the Default Document)? What path are you entering in your browser?

Comment: @Tim, this is a localhost of VS 2008 (local install on my machine). So I hit F5 to launch that app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the debugger - set a breakpoint at the start of the Page_Load method in the first page (possibly `/default.aspx`) and step through the code using F11 / F10